# regular expression to parse network interface config

Tags: python, regex

I am wondering if problem down here can be solved with one regular expression or I should make standard loop and evaluate line by line,

when I run included code I get `['Ethernet0/22', 'Ethernet0/24']`,
only result should be `['Ethernet0/23', 'Ethernet0/25']`.

any advice on this?

```
 import re

 txt='''#
 interface Ethernet0/22
  stp disable
  broadcast-suppression 5
  mac-address max-mac-count 1
  port access vlan 452
 #
 interface Ethernet0/23
  stp disable
  description BTO
  broadcast-suppression 5
  port access vlan 2421
 #
 interface Ethernet0/24
  stp disable
  description Avaya G700
  broadcast-suppression 5
  port access vlan 452
 #
 interface Ethernet0/25
  stp disable
  description BTO
  broadcast-suppression 5
  port access vlan 2421
 #
 '''

 re1 = '''^interface (.*?$).*?BTO.*?^#$'''

 rg = re.compile(re1,re.IGNORECASE|re.DOTALL|re.MULTILINE)
 m = rg.findall(txt)
 if m:
  print m
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that the regex is continuing to find the BTO in the next group.  As a quick workaround, you could just prohibit the "#" character in the interface id (assuming this isn't valid within records, and only seperates them).

```
re1 = '''^interface ([^#]*?$)[^#]*?BTO.*?^#$'''
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a little pyparsing parser for your file.  Not only does this show a solution to your immediate problem, but the parser gives you a nice set of objects that you can use to easily access the data in each interface.

Here is the parser:

```
from pyparsing import *

# set up the parser
comment = "#" + Optional(restOfLine)
keyname = Word(alphas,alphanums+'-')
value = Combine(empty + SkipTo(LineEnd() | comment))
INTERFACE = Keyword("interface")
interfaceDef = Group(INTERFACE + value("name") + \
    Dict(OneOrMore(Group(~INTERFACE + keyname + value))))

# ignore comments (could be anywhere)
interfaceDef.ignore(comment)

# parse the source text
ifcdata = OneOrMore(interfaceDef).parseString(txt)
```

Now how to use it:

```
# use dump() to list all of the named fields created at parse time
for ifc in ifcdata:
    print ifc.dump()

# first the answer to the OP's question
print [ifc.name for ifc in ifcdata if ifc.description == "BTO"]

# how to access fields that are not legal Python identifiers
print [(ifc.name,ifc['broadcast-suppression']) for ifc in ifcdata 
    if 'broadcast-suppression' in ifc]

# using names to index into a mapping with string interpolation
print ', '.join(["(%(name)s, '%(port)s')" % ifc for ifc in ifcdata ])
```

Prints out:

```
['interface', 'Ethernet0/22', ['stp', 'disable'], ['broadcast-suppression', '5'], ['mac-address', 'max-mac-count 1'], ['port', 'access vlan 452']]
- broadcast-suppression: 5
- mac-address: max-mac-count 1
- name: Ethernet0/22
- port: access vlan 452
- stp: disable
['interface', 'Ethernet0/23', ['stp', 'disable'], ['description', 'BTO'], ['broadcast-suppression', '5'], ['port', 'access vlan 2421']]
- broadcast-suppression: 5
- description: BTO
- name: Ethernet0/23
- port: access vlan 2421
- stp: disable
['interface', 'Ethernet0/24', ['stp', 'disable'], ['description', 'Avaya G700'], ['broadcast-suppression', '5'], ['port', 'access vlan 452']]
- broadcast-suppression: 5
- description: Avaya G700
- name: Ethernet0/24
- port: access vlan 452
- stp: disable
['interface', 'Ethernet0/25', ['stp', 'disable'], ['description', 'BTO'], ['broadcast-suppression', '5'], ['port', 'access vlan 2421']]
- broadcast-suppression: 5
- description: BTO
- name: Ethernet0/25
- port: access vlan 2421
- stp: disable
['Ethernet0/23', 'Ethernet0/25']
[('Ethernet0/22', '5'), ('Ethernet0/23', '5'), ('Ethernet0/24', '5'), ('Ethernet0/25', '5')]
(Ethernet0/22, 'access vlan 452'), (Ethernet0/23, 'access vlan 2421'), (Ethernet0/24, 'access vlan 452'), (Ethernet0/25, 'access vlan 2421')
```

Answer (score 2):

### An example without regular expressions:

```
print [ stanza.split()[0]
        for stanza in txt.split("interface ")
        if stanza.lower().startswith( "ethernet" )
        and stanza.lower().find("bto") > -1 ]
```

### Explanation:

I find compositions are best read "inside-out":

```
for stanza in txt.split("interface ")
```

Split the text on each occurrence of "interface " (including the following space). A resulting stanza will look like this:

```
Ethernet0/22
 stp disable
 broadcast-suppression 5
 mac-address max-mac-count 1
 port access vlan 452
#
```

Next, filter the stanzas:

```
if stanza.lower().startswith( "ethernet" ) and stanza.lower().find("bto") > -1
```

This should be self-explanatory.

```
stanza.split()[0]
```

Split the mathing stanzas on whitespace, and take the first element into the resulting list. This, in tandem with the filter `startswith` will prevent `IndexError`s

Comment: fixed. And it's OK nonetheless. I was overly pessimistic. Tested it now and it works just fine

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to make a pattern between the ^ and $ anchors, and relying on the # you could use the newlines break down the 'sublines' inside the single block match

e.g.  identify the clauses in terms of a sequence of literal not-newlines leading up to a newline.

something like

```
 re1 = '''\ninterface ([^\n]+?)\n[^\n]+?\n[^\n]+BTO\n'''
```

will produce the result you are after, from the source text provided.